# "KB2990941" "The update is not applicable to your computer"

Tags: windows-7, windows, ssd, nvme, samsung-ssd

I got an NVMe SSD. I intended to put it in my Linux machine but the only PCI Express slot that's free is too small. I put it into another machine, the problem is the one I put it into is my Windows 7 machine.

I heard I can get it to work in Windows 7 with KB2990941, but when I try to install that update on Win7 Pro x64 it says `"The update is not applicable to your computer"`

Can I get this to work, or do I have to move it to yet another machine? I can't install Windows 10 because I don't think this PC can boot from NVMe SSD.

It's a Dell Vostro 230 running Windows 7 that I am trying to install this to. So I can't even use this as a secondary storage drive is Vostro 230 isn't NVMe compatible? When I boot a Fedora 31 live CD I see a Samsung NVMe device.

[image: "The update is not applicable to your computer"]

Comment: If the PC does not support nvme, this is why the update fails. Post the make and model of pc that has the issue please

Comment: It's a Dell Vostro 230. So I can't even use this as a secondary storage drive is Vostro 230 isn't NVMe compatible? When I boot a Fedora 31 live CD I see a Samsung NVMe device.

Comment: The most likely reason for the update not to be applicable, is the fact, it’s been replaced by a newer update.  ** KB2990941** was released in 2015 and was likely replaced several times.

Comment: Do you know which update superseeds KB2990941?

Comment: Microsoft pulled the KB and recommends to upgrade to Windows 10, it was not superseded.

Comment: I was able to download it from elsewhere but get that message.

Comment: There is no solution to this problem, the patch in question, cannot be installed on your system.  If it was superseded, I don’t know which patch, since the update no longer exists on the Windows Update catalog.  **If it was pulled it was years ago**

Comment: I know MS no longer provides the update, but does that mean if it's not in the catalog you can't install it even if you download it from elsewhere, example https://forums.geshl2.com/index.php?topic=8950.0

Comment: @Ubuntu_Forums_Staff_Are_Trolls - The reason you are unable to install the update is due to the fact the update is not applicable to your installation.  That is the only reason you are unable to install it.  **You will be unable to install this particular update.**

Comment: Why is it not applicable, because Microsoft killed Windows7?

Comment: I've started to accept the reality I will not be able to access this drive in Windows 7, I never expected it to work with Windows 7 to begin with, it was meant for my other machine whose only PCIe slot the adapter will fit into is taken by the GFX card, but I thought I would try since there are others who claim to have not only used NVMe drives with Windows 7, but booted from them as well.

Comment: The update installs just fine here, and its only applicability requirement is SP1, besides of course architecture ([here](https://vantecusa.com/CKEdit/images/files/PC100_PC200_NVMe_Drivers_For_Windows7_ONLY.zip)'s both of them). Double check these two things.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft removed this hotfix from their repository as it's been discontinued. But if you've got the file from another source (e.g. device manufacturer's website), you should be able to install it on a PC that has not received any of the newer security and quality updates. This hotfix has not been superseded by any other update, but Microsoft probably added a patch in one of the newer security and quality updates to block any attempt to install this hotfix. You might want to insert this hotfix into the original installation media using dism and create an iso file for installing Windows on the target PC.